# More efficient than which way to subset elements of sublist based on multiple conditions

Tags: r, list

I have list `l` which is a list of lists.
Here is the structure

```
List of 3
 $ dbh: num [1:435(1d)] 105.5 104.6 98.3 98.3 82 ...
 $ npp: num [1:435(1d)] 2.10e-05 2.10e-05 1.75e-05 1.75e-05 1.89e-05 ...
 $ pft: int [1:435(1d)] 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 2 3 ...
 $ npl: int [1:435(1d)] 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 2 3
```

The issue I have is that I need to select all elements in the list `l$npp` and `l$npl` based on multiple conditions, for example pft=3 and dbh>100 and then multiply the selected elements `l$npl*l$npp` and sum the result. At the moment I am using the which statement but the code is really messy and convoluted

```
result=sum(l[['npp']][which(l[['dbh']]<10&l[['dbh']]>.13)&l[['pft']]==3)]]*l[['nplant']][which(l[['dbh']]<10&l[['dbh']]>100)]&l[['pft']]==3)])
```

Or something like that, you get the point how unreadable and convoluted this is. There must be a simpler way.

Comment: All list entries appear to have the same length. Why not make it a data.table and then go stepwise to your target.

Comment: @AndreElrico is correct, another option could be using "with" function to avoid subsetting the list every time : i.e. : `with(l, sum(npp[which(dbh < 10 & dbh>.13 ........)`

Comment: Some simple tips: 1. You should build a logical vector that performs the selection of the elements in a previous line. 2. As implied in 1, you don't need to use `which`. 3. digemall's suggestion of `with` will greatly reduce the `l[[...]]` clutter.

Comment: @digEmAll good idea, that makes things easier to read

Comment: @AndreElrico I tried that, it seems a very good approach. with works with lists and data.tables so it's a good idea, I just have to decided which one of the two I should use

Comment: I am not sure how you can do multiple operations with with, like sum and a multiplication, it seems I would need to do an intermediate step, first multiply than the sum.

Comment: Nevermind I just multiplied l$npp*l$nplant